# Errors while using the Google Maps Flash API

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, api, google-maps

my question today is dealing with the Google Maps Flash API.

I successfully created a basic map using Flash CS4 with the API here: http://gaban.com/googlemaps/

Now my problem is with the next basic tutorial dealing with a simple Info Window message. The Google DOCS example(FLEX) is here: ["Hello World"](http://gmaps-samples-flash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/MapInfoWindow.html)

Documentation here: [Google Maps Flash API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/flash/basics.html) (search for "Info Windows")

The example they show is this:

```
private function onMapReady(event:MapEvent):void {
map.setCenter(new LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13, MapType.NORMAL_MAP_TYPE);
map.openInfoWindow(getCenter(), new InfoWindowOptions({title: "Hello", content: "World"}));
}
```

## My code

```
import com.google.maps.LatLng;
import com.google.maps.Map;
import com.google.maps.MapEvent;
import com.google.maps.MapType;
import com.google.maps.MapOptions;

// ☼ ----------------------------

var map:Map = new Map();
    map.key="My API Key";
    map.setSize(new Point(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight));
    map.addEventListener(MapEvent.MAP_READY, onMapReady);

var stackLogo = new StackOverflow();
    stackLogo.x=290;
    stackLogo.y=329;

this.addChild(map);
this.addChild(stackLogo);


function onMapReady(event:Event):void {
    map.setCenter(new LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 14, MapType.NORMAL_MAP_TYPE);
    //map.openInfoWindow(getCenter(), new InfoWindowOptions({title: "Hello", content: "World"}));
}
```

^ The last commented line is the problematic line, it's also the exact same code in their example and I have all the listed `imports` so I don't know whats going on :(

**The errors I'm getting are from the same line:**

1180: Call to a possibly undefined method getCenter.

1180: Call to a possibly undefined method InfoWindowOptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is a typo on the page. Try

```
map.getCenter()
```

instead. See here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-flash/source/browse/trunk/samplecode/MapInfoWindow.mxml for the full code.

Comment: Sweet! That worked! :D I hate it when the actual API/code devs make errors like that, drives you nuts X_X... thx again